# python one line return value if availab if not return None

Tags: python

Lets say I have a variable `name = "Jack"`. I can check it like this

```
if name:
    return name
else:
    name = None
    return name
```

Is there any way to handle it in one line like:

`new_name = name if not return none` 
Which simply return the variable value if available and if not then it should return `None`

Comment: why not `return name if name else None`?

Comment: Sure it is possible in both Python 2.x (starting Python 2.5) and Python 3.x. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator . For Python pre-2.5 workarounds are possible.

Comment: In *this specific case* `return name or None` would also work, because you want to return `None` for any falsey value of name.

Comment: If you want to assign the `name` to `None` before return in case it is `None`, you could do it in *two* lines: 1. `name = name or None` 2. `return name`

Comment: You don't need that `else` there at all. Without an explicit `return`, it'll already `return` the value `None`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you could do it in one line as shown in my comment:

```
return name if name else None
```

Or even simpler for this specific case (as pointed out by Martijn):

```
return name or None
```

Comment: the 'or' solution would always work if the value you give priority to is placed first

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
return name if name else None
```

It works:

```
>>> def test_name(name):
...     return name if name else None
... 
>>> print test_name("")
None
>>> print test_name("Jack")
Jack
```

Comment: I want it to be it in variable `new_name = name if name else None`

Comment: @aryan your example will work

Comment: yes that worked... I was not printing so was not seeing the value