# How to convert this function from javascript to python?

Tags: javascript, python, function, syntax, syntax-error

**Does anybody know how to convert this javascript function to python ?**

javascript:

```
function ding(t, a, e, n) {
  return t > a && t <= e && (t += n % (e - a)) > e && (t = t - e + a), t
}
```

This is my try on doing so:

```
def ding(t, a, e, n):
    return t > a and t <= e and (t + n % (e - a)) > e and (t = (t - e + a)), t
```

It returns a **syntax error** at the "=" in  `(t = (t - e + a))`  and idk how to solve this right.

When giving it these values:  `ding(53, 47, 57, 97)`  it should return 50 in the original javascript function.

Comment: You need to use the walrus operator `:=` to use an assignment in an expression.

Comment: Python's comma operator isn't the same as JS's. You're creating a tuple in the python version.

Comment: I suggest you first convert the JS version to `if` syntax instead of ternary. Then it will be easier to see how to convert it to Python.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to do this all in one line with minified variable names?

Comment: @Barmar I tried doing so `t := (t - e + a)`, but it still returns a bad value 43, it should return 50

Comment: @Samathingamajig Not really, but I just got told to convert it as it is so ...

Comment: You also need to use `t := t + n % (e - a)`

Comment: Technicaly it would be possible to do this in one line with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315247/python-one-line-return-value-if-availab-if-not-return-none but it wouldn't be very clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a one-liner? Why not just split it into a few lines:

```py
def ding(t, a, e, n):
    if t > a and t <= e:
        t += n % (e - a)

        if t > e:
            t -= e - a
    
    return t
    
print(ding(53, 47, 57, 97)) # 50
```

Comment: You could also use Python's comparisong chaining `a < t <= e`

Comment: Thank's a lot, it works perfectly !

Comment: And no it doesn't have to be a one-liner :)

Answer (score 0):

that is because python doesn't support evaluating value assignment as assigned value. `(t = (t - e + a))` causes SyntaxError instead of returning `(t - e + a)`.

&& operators on the original code seems to be used to eliminate the usage of if operators. This should behave the same way as it did on JS.

```py
def ding(t, a, e, n):
    if a < t <= e:
        t += n % (e - a)
        if t > e:
            t -= (e - a)
    return t
```

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine !!